# PHP preg match ALL between two strings and return everything but the two string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string like this;

```
....className="someclass another_class" ... className="someclass1"
```

I want to capture all class names to end up with something like this.

```
someclass another_class
someclass1
```

I tried the following.

```
preg_match_all('#className="(.*?)"#',$string,$m_6df);
var_dump($m_6df[0]);
```

But then each class includes "className=" and '"' in it, like

```
'className="someclass"';
```

instead of just

```
'someclass';
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($m_6df);` and see what the full match is

Comment: @chris85 you're right. You should put that as the answer.

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks was just wondering why I was getting two of them, then I chose the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the `1` group, not `0`. The zero index is the whole matching pattern. `1` is the first capture group.

```
preg_match_all('#className="(.*?)"#','className="someclass another_class" ... className="someclass1"',$m_6df);
var_dump($m_6df[1]);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/534119